# Where does 1000 Amps save game progress?

Tags: windows, 1000-amps

In what location on the filesystem does 1000 Amps store your progress through the game when you save in game?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open this folder:

```
%appdata%\Macromedia\Flash Player\#SharedObjects\
```

You will find one randomly named folder, open it. From there:

```
localhost\program files\steam\steamapps\common\1000 amps\1000AmpsReWin.exe\
```

...has your booty.

Comment: Note: on a 64-bit system, it'll be `localhost\program files (x86)\steam\...`. Also, if Steam is installed somewhere other than Program Files (eg. on a separate partition), then it'l be `localhost\steam\...`.

Answer (score 0):

These are all the possible save game locations:

- Windows:`%APPDATA%\Macromedia\Flash Player\#SharedObjects\{random}\localhost\games\Desura\Common\1000-amps\1000AmpsReWin.exe`
- macOS (OS X): `~/Library/Application Support/Brandon Brizzi/1000 Amps/`
- Steam: `<path-to-game>/save`
- Steam Play (Linux): `<Steam-folder>/steamapps/compatdata/205690/pfx/`